# Creating in-app notifications with Ruby on Rails (like Facebook's notifications)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm a newbie with Ruby on Rails. I followed a railscast by [Gorails](https://gorails.com/episodes/in-app-navbar-notifications) on making In-App Navbar Notifications like Facebook. I don't have any errors but I'm unable to pull the notifications from the database.
When I run `http://localhost:3000/notifications.json`, all I get back is two brackets `[]`, despite logging-in as two separate users and posting reviews.

What am I missing?

These are my routes:

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users

  resources :listings do
    resources :reviews, except: [:show, :index] do
      put "upvote", to: "reviews#upvote"
      put "downvote", to: "reviews#downvote"
      resources :user
    end
  end

  get 'pages/about'

  get 'pages/how'

  get 'pages/faqs'

  get 'pages/contact'

  get 'pages/privacy'

  get 'pages/tos'

  get 'pages/guidelines'

  root 'listings#index'

  resources :notifications do 
    collection do
      post :mark_as_read
    end
  end

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

This is my Reviews Controller:

```html
def send_notifications
    review_obj = @review
    (@review.listing.reviews.uniq - [review_obj]).each do |rev|
      Notification.create(recipient: rev.user, actor: current_user, action: "posted", notifiable: @review)
    end
  end

  # POST /reviews
  # POST /reviews.json
  def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)
    @review.user_id = current_user.id
    @review.listing_id = @listing.id

    respond_to do |format|
        if @review.save
          # review = @review
          #create notifications to users
          
          send_notifications
          format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Your review was successfully posted.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @review }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

  # PATCH/PUT /reviews/1
  # PATCH/PUT /reviews/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|

      if @review.update(review_params)
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Your Review was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @review }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @review.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /reviews/1
  # DELETE /reviews/1.json
  def destroy
    @review.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to listing_path(@listing), notice: 'Your Review was successfully destroyed :(.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  #Added the def upvote and downvote
  def upvote
    @review = Review.find(params[:review_id])
    @review.upvote_from current_user
    send_notifications
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def downvote
    @review = Review.find(params[:review_id])
    @review.downvote_from current_user
    send_notifications
    redirect_to :back
  end
```

Here is my notifications controller:

```html
class NotificationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @notifications = Notification.where(recipient: current_user).last
  end

  def mark_as_read
    @notifications = Notification.where(recipient: current_user).unread
    @notifications.update_all(read_at: Time.zone.now)
    render json: {success: true}
  end
end
```

Here is my notification.js.coffee:

```html
class Notifications
  constructor: ->
    @notifications = $("[data-behavior='notifications']")

    if @notifications.length > 0
      @handleSuccess @notifications.data("notifications")
      $("[data-behavior='notifications-link']").on "click", @handleClick

      setInterval (=>
        @getNewNotifications()
      ), 5000

  getNewNotifications: ->
    $.ajax(
      url: "/notifications.json"
      dataType: "JSON"
      method: "GET"
      success: @handleSuccess
    )

  handleClick: (e) =>
    $.ajax(
      url: "/notifications/mark_as_read"
      dataType: "JSON"
      method: "POST"
      success: ->
        $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text(0)
    )

  handleSuccess: (data) =>
    items = $.map data, (notification) ->
      notification.template

    unread_count = 0
    $.each data, (i, notification) ->
      if notification.unread
        unread_count += 1

    $("[data-behavior='unread-count']").text(unread_count)
    $("[data-behavior='notification-items']").html(items)

jQuery ->
  new Notifications
```

Here's my `Notification` model:

```html
class Notification < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :recipient, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :actor, class_name: "User"
    belongs_to :notifiable, polymorphic: true

    scope :unread, ->{ where(read_at: nil) }
    #scope :recent, ->{ order(created_at: :desc).limit(5) }
end
```

Here is my view:

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
         <% if user_signed_in? && current_user.admin? %> 
            <li> <%= link_to 'Add New Listing', new_listing_path %> </li>
            <% end %> 
        
        <% if user_signed_in? %>

        <li class="nav-item btn-group" data-behavior="notifications" data-notifications='<%= render template: "notifications/index", formats: [:json] %>'>
          <a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" type="button" data-behavior="notifications-link" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           <span class ="glyphicon glyphicon-bell"></span><span data-behavior="unread-count"></span>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" data-behavior="notification-items">
          </div>
        
      <li class="dropdown">
         
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <%= current_user.first_name %> <%= current_user.last_name %> <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
            <% else %>
              <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Sign In", new_user_session_path %></li>
            <%  end %>
      </ul>
```

And this is my `notifications.json.jbuilder` file:

```html
json.array! @notification do |notification|
  json.id notification.id
  #json.recipient notification.recipient
  json.actor notification.actor.f_name
  json.action notification.action
  json.notifiable do #notification.notifiable
    json.type "a {notification.notifiable.class.to_s.underscore.humanize.downcase}"
  end
  json.url listing_review_path(notification.notifiable.listing_review, anchor: dom_id(notification.notifiable))
end
```

Comment: 2 suggestions: Have you checked in your console if there are any notifications with the same call? Also -- check your `notification.json.jbuilder` view. That is the file that dictates what is rendered for `/notifications.json`

Comment: Thank you @gwalshington, I checked and the notifications are being created with the same call. My notification.json.builder is where I suspect the problem to be... It's posted above after my view.. anything?